# Apache Airflow : Cannot trigger a new dag run with role - User

Tags: python-3.x, airflow, airflow-scheduler, airflow-2.x, airflow-api

I have recently upgraded my Airflow version from v1.10.6 to v2.2.3(Latest version). I created a user with role - User.

```
airflow users create \
    --role User \
    --username DEVUSER \
    --firstname DEV \
    --lastname USER \
    --email my_email@gmail.com
```

Password is devairflowuser

I'm trying to Trigger a new Dag Run using the below curl command :

```
curl -X POST 'http://localhost:8083/api/v1/dags/handling_migrations_task_request/dagRuns' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' --user "DEVUSER:devairflowuser" -d '{
}'
```

But, I get 401 error Unauthorized:

```
{
  "detail": null,
  "status": 401,
  "title": "Unauthorized",
  "type": "https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.2.3/stable-rest-api-ref.html#section/Errors/Unauthenticated"
}
```

In airflow.cfg

```
auth_backend = airflow.api.auth.backend.basic_auth
```

But, with Admin credentials I'm able to trigger a new Dag run.
From this - https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/security/access-control.html#user. I can see that Role-User can also create a Dag run

```
(permissions.ACTION_CAN_CREATE, permissions.RESOURCE_DAG_RUN)
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe try airflow sync-perm CLI command after you create the user